# How to make dropdown navbar full width

Tags: html, css, navbar

I have a nav bar with following HTML:

```
<nav id="menu-bar">
<ul>
  <li><a href='http://sunilpatro1985.blogspot.in/' >Home</a></li>
  <li><a href='http://sunilpatro1985.blogspot.in/search/label/SeleniumTesting'>Selenium</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href='http://sunilpatro1985.blogspot.in/2015/04/selenium-testng.html'>TestNG</a></li>
      <li><a href='http://sunilpatro1985.blogspot.com/2015/03/selenium-result-report-testng-ant.html'>ANT Reporting</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href='http://sunilpatro1985.blogspot.in/search/label/SoftwareTesting'>TestingConcepts</a></li>
  <li><a href='http://sunilpatro1985.blogspot.in/search/label/BasicJava' >JavaBasics</a></li>
  <li><a href='http://sunilpatro1985.blogspot.in/search/label/WindowsOS' >Windows</a></li>
  <li><a href='http://sunilpatro1985.blogspot.in/p/demo.html' >Demo</a></li>
</ul></nav>
```

and the CSS I used:

```css
#menu-bar {position: fixed; top: 0px; left: 0px; z-index: 999;height:0px;}
#menu-bar,#menu-bar a {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0px 0px;
border:none;
}
#menu-bar ul ul {
  display: none;
}
#menu-bar ul li:hover > ul {
  display: block;
}
#menu-bar ul {
  background: #efefef; 
  background: linear-gradient(top, #efefef 0%, #bbbbbb 100%);  
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #efefef 0%, #bbbbbb 100%); 
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #efefef 0%,#bbbbbb 100%); 
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 9px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
  padding: 0 20px;
  border-radius: 7px;  
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-table;
  overflow:visible;
}
#menu-bar ul:after {
  content: ""; clear: both; display: block;
}
#menu-bar ul li {
  float: left;
}
#menu-bar ul li:hover {
  background: #4b545f;
  background: linear-gradient(top, #4f5964 0%, #5f6975 40%);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #4f5964 0%, #5f6975 40%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #4f5964 0%,#5f6975 40%);
}
#menu-bar ul li:hover a {
  color: #fff;
}
#menu-bar ul li a {
  display: block; padding: 15px 30px;
  color: #757575; text-decoration: none;
}
#menu-bar ul ul {
  background: #5f6975; border-radius: 0px; padding: 0;
  position: absolute; top: 100%;
}
#menu-bar ul ul li {
  float: none; 
  border-top: 1px solid #6b727c;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #575f6a;
  position: relative;
}
#menu-bar ul ul li a {
  padding: 15px 30px;
  color: #fff;
}
#menu-bar ul ul li a:hover {
  background: #4b545f;
}
#menu-bar ul ul ul {
  position: absolute; left: 100%; top:0;
}
```

This above menu bar only covers 80% of my desktop screen. How can I make it full width? I tried some options as mentioned in other Stack Overflow answers, but nothing helped completely. Please help me make menu bar full width on screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't look like you're actually setting the nav element to be 100% of the width in the CSS. Try adding this:

```css
#menu-bar { width: 95%;}
#menu-bar > ul {width: 100% }
```

That worked in jsFiddle but you may need to adjust the percentage for menu-bar (the first line).

Answer (score 0):

Just add `right: 0` to `#menu-bar`:

```css
#menu-bar {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0; /* <-- here */
    z-index: 999;
    height: 0; /* why is the height "0"? */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```css
#menu-bar{width:100%}    
#menu-bar ul{width:100%}
```